# Mapbox How to select POI point from own style map on mobile?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mapbox

I am trying to use Mapbox mobile SDK to shows my information.
I just confused for How to select a POI on map,

Here is my problem:
I am using my style map, which had been combined my data inside. I wish to show the detail of the POI point by touch the point.
I have implemented this feature on my website version.

[image]

Now, I want to apply this feature on my mobile version.

[image]

and I have no idea that how to select a POI point from the map....

anyone can help me to workout It, please???

Also, my POI points are over 600000+. It is not possible to query a GEOJSON from a server. Especially, I have got so many points, and the GEOJSON file is extremely large than any other project (800MB). I can not make the POI like a simple "Annotation".

Comment: This questions perfectly acceptable here and is related to the Mapbox Android and iOS SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use query feature at to get the selected GeoJSON marker and add additional information. Check out [this indoor map example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/pull/154) that i'm currently working on. I add a GeoJSON source to the map and have an `onMapClickListener`. Inside of it I query the GeoJSON layer to determine which room the user selected. You should be able to do the same with a circle layer.

This features coming in both the next Android 4.2.0 and iOS releases (you can use the Android beta.3 for now). For more examples check out the [Demo app](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo). Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: hi sir, due to my Geojson is larger than anyone else (about 800-1GB.. yes it is a single Geojson file ) so I wish to query the detail from the MAP rather than query from a single huge geojson file...